# LaunchImage does not work for iPhone4s in newest Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

There is no option to import a LaunchImage for iPhone 4s in the new xcode, or is there? I cant seem to find it and have tried several things so far.

I have tried going to **Images.xcassetts** and creating a new LaunchImage source but this does not work.

This is the only options available in the newest Xcode:

[image]

The only other option is to create a new LaunchImage source like I said and add all of the launch images there, but that does not work for iPhone 4 either. Seems that no matter what I do I cannot get my splash screen to appear for iPhone 4s. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tap on right top corner button of your Xcode for Utilities you have the options for supporting different iOS devices [image]

Comment: Did my answer helped you ?