# Get the right LaunchImage not iPhone4's

Tags: ios, uiimage, launchimage

I'm accessing LaunchImage by [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage"] but it always gives me 640x960 no matter what. It obviously does not seem to detect which phone I'm using and it just throws 640x960.

I could check for the screen size and set specific image names for each device but that's not really ideal. There must be a simple way to just get this done.
Does anyone know?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062621/launchimage-does-not-work-for-iphone4s-in-newest-xcode?rq=1

Comment: I think you didn't even get what my problem is.. I'm asking how to easily access launch images for each device programmatically without having to check for screen sizes.

Comment: Found a blog about this "problem" and turns out it is impossible. Deleting this question soon.

Comment: wouldn't manually adding image to launch screen and performing auto layout help? @durazno

Comment: You're not listening to me.. that's already been done and I was asking something else. Really should've deleted this question sooner now I can't cuz some others have posted nonsensical answers..

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is that the `Info.plist` file contains information on which splash image to use. This method below will find that name from the `Info.plist`, and then you'll just have to query it from `[UIImage imageNamed:@""]` method.

```
- (NSString *)splashImageNameForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;
    NSString* viewOrientation = @"Portrait";
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        viewSize = CGSizeMake(viewSize.height, viewSize.width);
        viewOrientation = @"Landscape";
    }

    NSArray* imagesDict = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"UILaunchImages"];
    for (NSDictionary* dict in imagesDict) {
        CGSize imageSize = CGSizeFromString(dict[@"UILaunchImageSize"]);
        if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, viewSize) && [viewOrientation isEqualToString:dict[@"UILaunchImageOrientation"]])
            return dict[@"UILaunchImageName"];
    }

    if (imagesDict.count > 0) {
        return [imagesDict firstObject][@"UILaunchImageName"];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Why are you giving me this answer when I'd already specifically mentioned that I do know how. I just wanted to know if it was possible to do it WITHOUT having to check which device is being used.

Comment: Why can't we check for the size again?

Comment: Have you still not read my question..? I never said we couldn't we absolutely can and I know how. I said very clearly that I was looking for a way to skip that part if possible. The answer is we can't.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this url:

[Launch screens supporting iOS6 and iOS7 - forced to splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976412/launch-screens-supporting-ios6-and-ios7-forced-to-splash-screen)

or

you are add Launch Screen in Assets.xcassets:
you are see image size as below image:

[image]